# How to bind a collection of a subtype to a dependency property

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm creating a UserControl in WPF, that is able to work for any object of type `IMyNode`. Basically, it receives an ObservableCollection through a dependency property, register to it and do some stuff.

In one of my usecase, I use in a control that uses(and need), an ObservableCollection of `SomeSpecificNode`. `SomeSpecificNode` is an implementation of `IMyNode`.

Currently, I've a binding error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[SomeSpecificNode]' and 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[IMyNode]'.
```

I understand why it happens, it doesn't know how to convert automatically an `ObservableCollection<SomeSpecificNode>` to `ObservableCollection<IMyNode>`.

What would be the correct approach to do this?

Using a converter would break the `NotifyPropertyChange`. Using a `ObservableCollection<IMyNode>` in my parent ViewModel would not work for the other control in the same page.

Thank you!

Here some pseudo code:

```
public class SomeSpecificNode: IMyNode{
}
public interface IMyNode{

}



public class ParentViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<SomeSpecificNode> SelectedNodes {get;}=> new ObservableCollection<SomeSpecificNode>()

}


<UserControl x:Class="ParentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ch.VibroMeter.Xms.Configurators.Controls.ActionBar"
             xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ParentViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="RootContainer">
        <SomeChildControl Nodes="{Binding SelectedNodes}" /><!-- This binding will fail !-->
    </StackPanel
</UserControl>



public partial class ParentView : UserControl
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NodesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Nodes), typeof(ObservableCollection<IMyNode>), typeof(ParentView), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<IMyNode>), OnNodesChanged));

        private static void OnNodesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //...
        }

        public  ObservableCollection<IMyNode>  Nodes
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<IMyNode>)GetValue(NodesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NodesProperty, value); }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me with a minimum source code?

Comment: @james.lee I added some pseudo code of the important parts.

Comment: @J4N: Change the type of the dependency property to a compatible type such as `IEnumerable<IMyNode>`? You can obviosuly only set a  `ObservableCollection<IMyNode>` property to a `ObservableCollection<IMyNode>` or `null` and nothing else. There is no "fix" for this. It's how a strongly typed programming language work.

Comment: @mm8 I was hopping that with some covariant declaration I could find a way. My understanding is that having a `IEnumerable<IMyNode>` dependency property would not allow me to assign  `IEnumerable<SomeSpecificNode>` to it even if `SomeSpecificNode` is an `IMyNode`?. So I imagine I could set my dependency property to accept a `IList` but that seems dirtier. What you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the type of the dependency property to a compatible type such as `IEnumerable<IMyNode>`.

You cannot set an `ObservableCollection<IMyNode>` property to anything else than an `ObservableCollection<IMyNode>` or `null`.

An `ObservableCollection<SomeSpecificNode>` is *not* an `ObservableCollection<IMyNode>` but it is an `IEnumerable<IMyNode>` assuming that `SomeSpecificNode` implements `IMyNode`.

So this compiles just fine;

```
IEnumerable<IMyNode> collection = new ObservableCollection<SomeSpecificNode>();
```

But this doesn't:

```
ObservableCollection<IMyNode> collection = new ObservableCollection<SomeSpecificNode>(); //Cannot implictly convert type...
```

The difference is that `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) for more information.

Comment: Great. Do you know if there is an `IEnumerable` flavor that also implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. I heavily rely on it for this control.

Comment: No, but you could cast the `IEnumerable<T>` to  an `INotifyCollectionChanged` at runtime using the `as` or `is` operator.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be an improvement over my current implementation, its just that this component require to have something observable to work, so it would technically allow invalid types. But if there is no other solution, it's already better.

Comment: I don't think there is any better solution for the built-in `ObservableCollection<T>` type.